# No `active` command in anaconda in Windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm using `anaconda` on Windows. I followed the `conda` instructions to install python 3; however, there's no command named `active` on my system. Where does this command come from? I guess it is from `anaconda`, and I searched the anaconda installation folder, still no luck. Any clue to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link to the instructions you are trying to follow.

Comment: The command is `activate`, not `active`.

Comment: @WolfgangUlmer Yes, I miss spelled the the command, my bad. Thanks! I guess this question is worthless, so I should delete it.